# WSF/PHP install error - Making all in savanc /bin/bash: line 17: cd: savanc: No such file or directory

Tags: php, wso2

with PHP 5.3+ I get this error at the make stage of the install instructions;

```
Making all in savanc /bin/bash: line 17: cd: savanc: No such file or directory
```

Then I tried with an older PHP 5.2.x an get this error at same stage:

```
fatal error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
```

Yes LIBXML2 is install, I would prefer to get it installed on latest VM but even the older one will do just need to know how to get past those errors. somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this file

[build.sh](https://github.com/wso2/wsf/blob/master/php/build.sh)

You will see options for `./configure`. One of them is `--enable-savan=no`

I'm not sure this is solution, but try to use it!